# Orient ETL for document db

Tags: etl, orientdb

I am able to import data into orient document db as plain documents,can anyone please help me or share configuration file to embed a list inside a document ?

Comment: Too generic question. Have you checked the online docs first? http://orientdb.com/docs/last/ETL-Introduction.html

Comment: Yes, I have checked the docs ,but i was not able to find any sample's which shows how to embed a list in a document using ETL configuration